# High %soft CPU usage during high network load on ixgbe

Tags: networking, performance

We have an Intel 82598EB 10GBE NIC. The network load is composed of lot of small sized UDP packets. To simulate a DDoS, from another server we pushed ~100k pps small UDP packet (just some Mbit of bandwidth). When we do, %soft CPU usage goes to 100% making the server unusable and dropping packets.

Kernel is 3.8.5, ixgbe 3.13.10
We have already made some tunings to lower interrupts rate (rx-usecs: 300) but didn't solve the problem. Is there a way to check why softirqs use so much CPU even if interrupts rate is not high?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old; but I'm mainly replying for users who come here with similar issues.

There are a few ways to check interrupts:

- `cat /proc/interrupts` records interrupts per CPU and IO device.
- `grep cpu /proc/stat` column 6 and 7 contain `irq` and `softirq` stats.
- `top` and `htop`; observe `si` and if you change htop to advanced display mode for CPUs you can see `si` and `hi`.
- To get historical data install `sysstat`; to get specific interrupt data see `sar -I XALL`.
- You can also use `perf`.

Since this is most likely a driver issue (or the NIC is failing) I'd check for any `overruns` or `errors` on the interface; if there are none see if there is an update to the driver.